# Once again something works in Remix JVM but does not work in Rinkeby. Why?

Tags: remix, rinkeby

Hello Solidity Expert,

I am attempting to solve Ethernaut problem 9 titled King. [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/)

On Remix, when I deploy contract King and subsequently deploy contract SendContractEther with King's contract address followed by calling sendEtherToContract() I am able to successfully run King's fallback function and everything works as expected.

When I do the above on Rinkeby, nothing happens?  Why?

Thank you

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract King {

  address payable king;
  uint public prize;
  address payable public owner;

  constructor() public payable {
    owner = msg.sender;  
    king = msg.sender;
    prize = msg.value;
  }

  fallback() external payable {
    require(msg.value >= prize || msg.sender == owner);
    king.transfer(msg.value);
    king = msg.sender;
    prize = msg.value;
  }

  function _king() public view returns (address payable) {
    return king;
  }
}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.7.4;

contract SendContractEther {
    
    address payable public contractAddress ;
    
    // Assign the address of the Contract
    constructor(address payable _contractAddress) payable {
        contractAddress = _contractAddress;
    }
    
    function sendEtherToContract() external payable {

        contractAddress.call{value: address(this).balance, gas: 3000000}("");

    }
    
    function etherBalance () external view returns (uint256) {
        
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the failed transaction hash?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this Ismael.  On Rinkeby the transaction completes with success but it doesn't change the state variables in the King contract when I call sendEtherToContract.  On Remix JVM the state variables are updated as expected when I call sendEtherToContract.  Rinkeby transaction hash: 0xe0b7517be53969e4793bb8b7643d19d6d7eba1177a15ca2ba6e7889ca337fe18

Comment: From the error message King's fallback function is failing with not enough gas. From the transaction [trace](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xe0b7517be53969e4793bb8b7643d19d6d7eba1177a15ca2ba6e7889ca337fe18) the failure seems to be at `king.transfer(msg.value)`. I'd suggest to try with more gas, the 35k seems low, try 1M gas.

Comment: Thank you Ismael.  It was out of Gas on Rinkeby.  In the Remix JVM if it's out of Gas it throws an error in the console but when injecting with Rinkeby it doesn't throw an error in the Console.  Regardless, I increased the Gas in MetaMask and it works.  Thanks again Ismael.  I am glad I got this resolved.